# React Native ios BUILD FAILED after upgrading from 0.66.5 to 0.72.3

Tags: ios, react-native, upgrade, react-native-upgrade

I recently upgraded the react native on my project from 0.66.5 to 0.72.3 and now the build fails to run the ios app with the following error:

I made the upgrade following this changelog:
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.5&to=0.72.3

I already deleted and the ios/Pods and ios/Pods.lock file multiple times but still no success.

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myAppName-dywhntqrtcicsvatwhfcyxabaynr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myAppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myAppName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o 

/Users/mac/Codebase/personal/myapp-name/app/ios/myAppName/AppDelegate.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'myAppName' from project 'myAppName')
(1 failure)
```

Here is my `Procfile`

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'myAppName' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'myAppName Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

This is my `AppDelegate.mm` file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"myAppName";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

Comment: try deleting your DerivedData folder also and then build it.

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: can you please share some more information about the error,Mostly it's derived data issue,you can try to reinstall the pods and then restart Xcode with cleared derived data.Might me worked.